# How to implement Circular Animation in a Div Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I'm modifying this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/sapweqaq/), but my problem is that I can't make it circle around a certain direction.

```
  .dice-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    top: 209px;
    right: -9px;
    /* left: 50%; */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    font-family: 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'WenQuanYi Micro Hei', sans-serif;
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
       -moz-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
         -o-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
            animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                      IE 10+, Safari 5 */
}

    @-webkit-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

    @-moz-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

    @-o-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

    @keyframes myOrbit {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-300deg); }
}
```

This should be the behavior [image]

Explanation of behavior: It will circle around and follow the arrow and it will return in the original position.

This should only animate when the user click the button not infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IF IT SHOULD STOP AFTER RELEASE

The animation should be started in the active state. In your code, it is not in the active state so it gets started when page is loaded. Sure, it cannot be activated when pressing another button.

Try fix it with:

```
.dice-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    top: 209px;
    right: -9px;
    /* left: 50%; */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    font-family: 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'WenQuanYi Micro Hei', sans-serif;
}
.dice-wrapper:active { // :active is the pseudo class when mouse is down
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
       -moz-animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Firefox 5-15 */
         -o-animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Opera 12+ */
            animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                  IE 10+, Safari 5 */
}
// Keyframes...
```

When you use this, the animation will play when the button is pressed, and on release, it will stop.

#### IF IT SHOULD NOT STOP AFTER RELEASE

If you don't want to use JavaScript, it is impossible.

Using JavaScript, your css should be:

```
.dice-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    top: 209px;
    right: -9px;
    /* left: 50%; */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    font-family: 'Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', 'WenQuanYi Micro Hei', sans-serif;
}
.dice-wrapper.pressed { // .pressed class will be added in JavaScript
    -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
       -moz-animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Firefox 5-15 */
         -o-animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Opera 12+ */
            animation: myOrbit 4s linear; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                  IE 10+, Safari 5 */
}
// Keyframes...
```

> Note that `:active` is replaced by `.pressed`

In JavaScript, add the `pressed` class when pressed (i'm using jQuery):

```
$(".dice-wrapper").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("pressed"); // Activate the animation
})
```

Replace `click` by `mousedown` if you want to start the animation when the mouse is down on the button.
You can also another button. Use the `setTimeout` function to stop the animation.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("pressed");
})
setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("pressed")
}, 2000); // 2 seconds = 2000 milliseconds
```